# Transversal CNOT implementation on stim

Tags: quantum-gate, error-correction, stim

Re: a recent paper on the arXiv, Correlated decoding of logical algorithms with transversal gates (https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.03272). As MWPM (pymatching and stim) cannot handle errors that flip more than two checks, are there any other ways of doing the transversal cnot decoding via modifying the decoding in a clever manner? I found an old paper that alludes to some kind of correlated decoding without the need for hypergraphs (https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/pdf/10.1103/PRXQuantum.2.020341, citation 104 and 113). Can anyone advice on this? Thanks[image]